# Can't read text file content generated by `wmic logicaldisk get name > D:\sample.txt` using batch script

Tags: batch-file, cmd, wmic

I want to read the text file generated by `wmic logicaldisk get name > D:\sample.txt` using batch script. The problem is that it doesn't print the content on the screen. But when I try to copy its content and paste on a new txt file, it displays the content. Here is my batch script code.

```
@echo off 
FOR /F "usebackq tokens=1,2* delims=" %%G IN ("D:\sample.txt") DO echo %%G
pause
```

Comment: Change it to `FOR /F "skip=1 delims=" %%G IN ('type "D:\sample.txt"') DO echo %%G`

Comment: but why pipe to file then read? just do: `for /F "skip=1" %%i in ('wmic logicaldisk get name') do echo %%i`

Comment: @Compo It works! Can you explain why?

Comment: @GerhardBarnard your first guess is not working. I'm not expert in batch script that's why I separated the commands.

Comment: my bad, I formatted incorrectly, deleted that comment though because I can no longer edit it.

Comment: The most reliable way (without a temporary file) is: `for /F "skip=1 delims=" %%G in ('wmic LogicalDisk get DeviceID') do for /F %%H in ("%%G") do echo/%%H` (this method avoids artefacts like orphaned carriage-return characters coming from conversion of the Unicode output of `wmic` to ASCII/ANSI text)

Comment: @aschipfl You're right. Is `DeviceID` is more reliable than `name`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of piping to file, why not do the output from command directly though?

```
@for /F "skip=1" %%i in ('wmic logicaldisk get name') do @echo %%i
```

Or to have it in a row instead of list:

```
@echo off
for /F "skip=1" %%i in ('wmic logicaldisk get deviceid') do <nul Set /P "=%%i"
```

Comment: Can you explain why my code doesn't work? Was it because of `name` command in a textfile?

Comment: @James: no, it was because `wmic` outputs Unicode, but `cmd` works with Ansi. `Type` converts Unicode to Ansi "on the fly", that's why Comp's solution works.

Comment: @Stephan Thanks! Haven't thought that one. :)